# How to set ValidatesOnDataErrors from codebehind

Tags: wpf

In WPF how do I set the ValidatesOnDataErrors property for the binding on a control (e.g. a TextBox)? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a property of the [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) class. You can construct bindings in code, set the property and use [`SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setbinding.aspx) on the `TextBox`.

You can use [`GetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbinding.aspx) to get existing bindings, but you *cannot* modify them once they are in use...

Comment: I was trying to set ValidatesOnDataErrors to true on the lostfocus event of a control but it threw an exception saying that a Binding cannot be changed after it has been used. Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Comment: You can create a new Binding object, and then use the SetBinding method to associate it to the correct DependencyProperty (TextProperty, for example), as H.B. said.

Comment: @DukeCyrillus You should be setting `ValidatesOnDataErrors` at the same time you set the `Binding`, not in the `LostFocus` event

Comment: @DukeCyrillus: As i already said you can construct a binding and set it, you can transfer properties from the old binding object if need be...

Comment: I did not want certain controls to validate unless they had been visited at least once which is why I was trying to reset the binding in the LostFocus event. Not sure if there was a better way but creating a new binding and re-setting it to the property seems to have worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `ValidatesOnDataErrors` is a property of a binding, not of a control.

So look for the correct binding of the control (in my example, the TextProperty dependency property)...

Try this:

```
System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression binding = this.textBox1.GetBindingExpression(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.TextProperty);
binding.ParentBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
```

Comment: Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.